# What does 「片付けといてくれ」 mean?

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate some text, but I hit a sentence that I could not understand completely.

> 悪いんだがここ**片付けといてくれ**

From what I read up to now, this means something like "This place is in bad shape. Clean it." roughly speaking, but I am having trouble understanding the 片付けといてくれ part. [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%89%87%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C) simplifies it to 片付けて, but there seems to be so much lost in this simplification. What exactly does this extra part mean?

Comment: Are you familiar with 〜ておく?

Comment: @snailboat It means some thing like "going to", right? Like in an uncertain future.

Comment: 悪いんだが = sorry to trouble you but. 片付けといてくれ = 片付け + て + おい + て + くれ, and くれ is a casual (and somewhat curt) form of ください (= please). Thus 悪いんだがここ片付けといてくれ = would you mind cleaning up this place (while I am out)?

Comment: 悪いんだが = sorry to trouble you and といてくれ = would you mind ? great keigo usage.

Comment: @oldergod ふふふ　職場でそのまま使っちゃたらやば～いｗｗ

Comment: @Choko: <職場でそのまま使っちゃたらやば～い> Probably. The phrase sounds kind of "Mind cleaning up this place, wiil-ya? (Coz I wanna go out.)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to wrap up.

〜しておく = (be sure) to do 〜

悪いんだが (<- 悪い + の + だ + が)= sorry to trouble you but

片付けといてくれ = 片付け + て + おい (<- おく) + て + くれ

where くれ is a casual (and somewhat curt) form of ください (= please).

Thus, together

悪いんだがここ片付けといてくれ = would you mind cleaning up this place (while I am out)?

But the original phrase sounds much less polite. So I would suggest "Mind cleaning up this place, will ya? (Coz I wanna go out.)"